# No WiFi adaptor found + Cable Unplugged Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my notebook along with Windows (which came pre-installed). However, I cannot connect to wi-fi because there is a "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" message. I found many solutions online which mostly said connect to Ethernet and download the required drivers.

However, when I try to connect through ethernet it shows `cable unplugged`. Now, I cannot access the internet either through LAN or through WiFi.

However, in my Windows WiFi and LAN, both are working. I searched for many online solutions however none seemed to help. Could anyone help me?

- Model: [Mi Notebook 14 (Horizon Edition)](https://www.mi.com/in/mi-notebook-14-horizon/)

Edit

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

- `uname -a` Output:

`Linux Vallabh-MI 5.0.0-23-generic #24~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 29 16:12:28 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

- `dmesg | grep iwl` Output

````
[    2.525688] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x354
[    7.543679] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[    7.543682] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[    7.543683] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device config registers:
[    7.543713] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 02f08086 00100406 02800000 00800010 b6198004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    7.543714] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00348086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 000001ff
[    7.543715] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[    7.543745] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 00489004 00000040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    7.543747] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000011 0c040005 00000351 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 001f0040
[    7.543765] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[    7.543768] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    7.543770] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    7.765532] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0x0bad1122]
[    7.778763] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   12.200631] Modules linked in: cmac bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio joydev intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel hid_multitouch hid_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul i915 snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event nouveau ghash_clmulni_intel snd_rawmidi kvmgt vfio_mdev snd_seq mdev btusb vfio_iommu_type1 btrtl iwlmvm btbcm mxm_wmi vfio btintel aesni_intel snd_seq_device aes_x86_64 kvm ttm mac80211 snd_timer bluetooth crypto_simd irqbypass cryptd idma64 virt_dma glue_helper drm_kms_helper snd input_leds intel_cstate iwlwifi drm intel_rapl_perf i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops serio_raw sparse_keymap intel_wmi_thunderbolt ecdh_generic syscopyarea intel_lpss_pci processor_thermal_device sysfillrect cfg80211 soundcore sysimgblt wmi_bmof intel_soc_dts_iosf intel_lpss int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone mac_hid int3400_thermal acpi_tad acpi_thermal_rel```
````

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have edited and added the output

Comment: I suggest to disable Windows Fast Startup feature and boot to Ubuntu again. It is a well known issue with dual boot.

Comment: @Pilot6 okay, let me try that and update.

Comment: @Pilot6: "boot to Ubuntu again." Meaning, reinstall it? As I disabled Windows Fast Startup Feature and nothing changed in Ubuntu

Comment: OK, let's dig further. What is the kernel. Please add `uname -a` output and also `dmesg | grep iwl`.

Comment: @Pilot6 have edited and added the output. Sorry for the late reply!

Comment: How happened that you have the 5.0 kernel on current Ubuntu 18.04. Update the system, and the prob;em most likely will be resolved. Don't tell me that you can't. You can always use your phone.

Comment: @Pilot6 okay. Thank you for the help